# NETMF invoke .NET methods from C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, embedded, .net-micro-framework

Is it possible to make a native C++ app thats boots up NETMF and tells it to load a .NET EXE or DLL that I can in turn invoke a method in that lib or app?

I want to use NETMF the same way you can use "Embedded Mono" but want to use NETMF so I can compile and run .NET code on platforms Mono doesn't run on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile .NET Micro for x86](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26476054/compile-net-micro-for-x86)

Comment: Yes it is, forgot I made this post.