# Compile .NET Micro for x86

Tags: c#, .net, clr, .net-micro-framework

I'm totally at a loss about the build process in the .NET micro source code.
How am I suppose to build the source?  There are project files that are not compatible with VS and the "BuildLauncher.exe" has no clear directions as to how I should be using it?

I want to try and see how hard it would be to compile a runtime for embedding .NET in a native desktop application.

Comment: While it could probably be compiled for the desktop, the loss of direct I/O pins would be significant. A normal x86 Processor depends on the South Bridge for external communication and then most of it is through higher Level Interfaces such as PCI, USB, SATA/IDE that would each require low level drivers.  I don't think you would get the benefit from it that you are thinking. Visual Studio includes a Simulator for debugging, but even that doesn't really support I/O so it's limited to debugging logic flow.

Comment: I'm just wanting to use the base runtime embedded and launched from a C++ app so I can target platforms Mono does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP's comment to JohnD is confusing because it references C++ on a desktop and C# on an 8-Bit CPU. If the OP could clarify the actual end goal, there might be a more specific answer to their question. Although I think this information may be helpful.

The .NET Micro Framework requires a 32-bit MicroController, see https://netmf.codeplex.com/documentation at the bottom is the "Porting Kit Datasheet".

Currently the framework runs on these 32-bit processor cores.

ARM v4, ARM Thumb, Thumb-2, Blackfin, SH2/2A

Also not many 8-Bit MicroControllers have enough memory.
The memory requirements for the .NET Micro Framework depend entirely on which features you use. In its smallest form, the framework requires 64 Kb of RAM and 256 Kb of flash memory.

In order to port the MicroFramework to a currently unsupported MicroController see the previously mentioned document and the "HowTo Manual for PKStudio" on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Micro Framework is built for [embedded devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_system) (ie. micro controllers), not embedding in normal desktop applications. The [project showcase](http://www.netmf.com/project-showcase/) should give you a good example of what NETMF is capable of.

Comment: I know it was intended to be used only on embedded platforms.  But the CLR should still be capable of running on a desktop if booted from a native C++ app.  I've done embedded programming with Micro .NET and Arduino.  My goal is to have C# run on 8-bit CPUs for indie game systems.